# Gerar relatórios em c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relatório

alguém sabe me indicar um gerador de relatório free para .Net. Por exemplo, em Java conheço o Jasper que é muito bom, mas para .net não estou encontrando nada.

O que preciso é um relatório simples, buscando em uma tabela minha....Não terá nem imagens, mas a única coisa que preciso é que o título eu coloque um background cinza e tenha número de páginas....

Comment: Amigo, especifique o tipo de report que voce quer gerar.

Comment: Word, Excel....?

Comment: Este tipo de pergunta é difícil de ser respondida aqui. Você pode até obter uma lista de compras, mas ela não tem significado. Pelo menos da forma como a pergunta está feita, você está pedindo por opiniões sem base.

Comment: Pesquisei por "free C# report builder" no google e vieram vários links como [este](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788923/reporting-free-open-source-alternatives-to-crystal-reports-in-winforms) e [este outro](http://beinghappyprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/reports-in-csharp-free-tools-suitable-for-commercial-projects/). Como o @bigown disse acima, especifique que tipo de gerador, para qual caso e o que precisa ter, por exemplo

Comment: @f.fujihara o que precisava era que saísse aquela que a pessoa visualiza o relatório antes de imprimir, e depois a pessoa iria imprimir. Não precisa nem gerar arquivo...

Comment: @Silva Parece estar bem confuso o que voce quer, minha sugestão é quie voce mostre em uma modal então. Já que não haverá a necessidade de gerar arquivo, em uma grid ou qualquer coisa do tipo.

Answer (score 3):

Eu uso o **[`iTextSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/)** e o **[`PDFSharp`](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp)** para gerar relatórios, grids e requisições, esses dois são os mais populares para dotNet. Um deles vai resolver o seu problema.

Comment: muito obrigado...Deu certo o que falou...era realmente o que eu precisava....Vou utilizar o iTextSharp

Comment: @Silva Para ajudar marca como certa a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o relatório simples tipo `StringBuilder` e **retorne os valores à um perfil de saída**.